# Docker mount not putting files to the hosts directory

Tags: docker, centos

I have created a mount on my container which maps a physical path on the server to a path within the docker container. However, when files are placed within the containers path, those files are not appearing on the servers path (and vice versa)

Here is my docker run cmd:

```
docker run -d -p 127.0.0.1:7001:5000 --name myContainer myContainer -v /var/www/Images:/app/wwwroot/
```

Server is running CentOS. My application that runs within this docker container places files in the `app/wwwroot` folder within its container. I expected these files to also appear on the servers `/var/www/Images` folder but they do not.

Any ideas why?

Thanks

Comment: Are the container able to write to the path? do you see inside the container the files are there? because I assume, you must chown of the host directory to allow the container to write in.

Comment: The files are definitely appearing within the container, in the app/wwwroot directory. I will double check the permissions on the host file directory, it did look okay first time I looked.

Comment: Can you please try -v /var/www/Images:/app/wwwroot/:z this maybe help you.

Comment: That didn't work unfortunately. The files are being placed into app/wwwroot as expected, but nothing is appearing in the hosts directory folder

Comment: Since the `-v` option is after the image name `myContainer`, it's passed as an argument to the program running in the container.  Try moving the `-v` option before the image name.

Comment: I think that may have solved the issue, my uploaded files are now appearing in the host directory and also within the docker containers app/wwwroot path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I expected these files to also appear on the servers /var/www/Images
> folder but they do not.

You map mount a directory or path `/app/wwwroot` will be overridden (hide) by the host files, as `-v` option tells to the docker I am going to override anything inside Docker with host files.

> When you use a bind mount, a file or directory on the host machine is mounted into a container. The file or directory is referenced by its full or relative path on the host machine.

[bind-mounts](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/)

Or if you expect to copy from container then one way is to start container

```
docker run -it --rm --name test my_container
```

then copy files from container

```
docker cp my_container:/app/wwwroot/  /var/www/Images
```

Now bind you have docker files under `/var/www/Images`.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the explanation.

Is using file mounts in my example of no use to me? As I want the files to appear in a folder outside the container. I.e my application uploads files to the containers app/wwwroot folder. I then want these files to be outside the container on the servers directory somewhere.

Comment: It's not possible in this as it will be hidden by host files, this is default behaviour. you can add some logic to copy during run time

Comment: I see, is there any way to achieve what I am trying to do. Perhaps using volume storage in docker?

Comment: Yes, you add this trick in entrypoint, I'll update answer shortly